# Failed to fetch deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_5.10.70-1_amd64.deb

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, updates, docker

I am getting the following error on running `docker-compose -f docker-compose-mssql.yml up -d --build --remove-orphans`  in my project.

> E: Failed to fetch
> http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_5.10.70-1_amd64.deb
> 404  Not Found [IP: 199.232.22.132 80]

> E: Unable to fetch some
> archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

[image]

Complete log below:

```
WARNING: Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 1
WARNING: Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 2
WARNING: Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 3
Building flask-dev
Sending build context to Docker daemon  756.2kB
Step 1/19 : FROM python:3.7-slim
 ---> 3e12d0db6381
Step 2/19 : ENV APP_HOME /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 547384aa23b8
Step 3/19 : WORKDIR ${APP_HOME}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 44ceae2297e4
Step 4/19 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 52fa30e15a2f
Step 5/19 : RUN apt-get --assume-yes update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 47be10d9ea1c
Step 6/19 : RUN apt-get --assume-yes install freetds-dev freetds-bin
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 177aac289cf6
Step 7/19 : RUN apt-get install gcc -y
 ---> Running in b92d29973cf4
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  binutils binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu cpp cpp-10
  fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core gcc-10 libasan6 libatomic1 libbinutils
  libbrotli1 libc-dev-bin libc-devtools libc6-dev libcc1-0 libcrypt-dev
  libctf-nobfd0 libctf0 libdeflate0 libfontconfig1 libfreetype6 libgcc-10-dev
  libgd3 libgomp1 libisl23 libitm1 libjbig0 libjpeg62-turbo liblsan0 libmpc3
  libmpfr6 libnsl-dev libpng16-16 libquadmath0 libtiff5 libtirpc-dev libtsan0
  libubsan1 libwebp6 libx11-6 libx11-data libxau6 libxcb1 libxdmcp6 libxpm4
  linux-libc-dev manpages manpages-dev sensible-utils ucf
Suggested packages:
  binutils-doc cpp-doc gcc-10-locales gcc-multilib make autoconf automake
  libtool flex bison gdb gcc-doc gcc-10-multilib gcc-10-doc glibc-doc
  libgd-tools man-browser
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binutils binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu cpp cpp-10
  fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core gcc gcc-10 libasan6 libatomic1
  libbinutils libbrotli1 libc-dev-bin libc-devtools libc6-dev libcc1-0
  libcrypt-dev libctf-nobfd0 libctf0 libdeflate0 libfontconfig1 libfreetype6
  libgcc-10-dev libgd3 libgomp1 libisl23 libitm1 libjbig0 libjpeg62-turbo
  liblsan0 libmpc3 libmpfr6 libnsl-dev libpng16-16 libquadmath0 libtiff5
  libtirpc-dev libtsan0 libubsan1 libwebp6 libx11-6 libx11-data libxau6
  libxcb1 libxdmcp6 libxpm4 linux-libc-dev manpages manpages-dev
  sensible-utils ucf
0 upgraded, 52 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 54.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 192 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 sensible-utils all 0.0.14 [14.8 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 manpages all 5.10-1 [1412 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 ucf all 3.0043 [74.0 kB]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 binutils-common amd64 2.35.2-2 [2220 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libbinutils amd64 2.35.2-2 [570 kB]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libctf-nobfd0 amd64 2.35.2-2 [110 kB]
Get:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libctf0 amd64 2.35.2-2 [53.2 kB]
Get:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu amd64 2.35.2-2 [1809 kB]
Get:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 binutils amd64 2.35.2-2 [61.2 kB]
Get:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libisl23 amd64 0.23-1 [676 kB]
Get:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libmpfr6 amd64 4.1.0-3 [2012 kB]
Get:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libmpc3 amd64 1.2.0-1 [45.0 kB]
Get:13 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 cpp-10 amd64 10.2.1-6 [8528 kB]
Get:14 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 cpp amd64 4:10.2.1-1 [19.7 kB]
Get:15 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 fonts-dejavu-core all 2.37-2 [1069 kB]
Get:16 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 fontconfig-config all 2.13.1-4.2 [281 kB]
Get:17 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libcc1-0 amd64 10.2.1-6 [47.0 kB]
Get:18 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libgomp1 amd64 10.2.1-6 [99.9 kB]
Get:19 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libitm1 amd64 10.2.1-6 [25.8 kB]
Get:20 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libatomic1 amd64 10.2.1-6 [9008 B]
Get:21 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libasan6 amd64 10.2.1-6 [2065 kB]
Get:22 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 liblsan0 amd64 10.2.1-6 [828 kB]
Get:23 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libtsan0 amd64 10.2.1-6 [2000 kB]
Get:24 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libubsan1 amd64 10.2.1-6 [777 kB]
Get:25 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libquadmath0 amd64 10.2.1-6 [145 kB]
Get:26 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libgcc-10-dev amd64 10.2.1-6 [2328 kB]
Get:27 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 gcc-10 amd64 10.2.1-6 [17.0 MB]
Get:28 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 gcc amd64 4:10.2.1-1 [5192 B]
Get:29 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libbrotli1 amd64 1.0.9-2+b2 [279 kB]
Get:30 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libc-dev-bin amd64 2.31-13+deb11u2 [275 kB]
Get:31 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libpng16-16 amd64 1.6.37-3 [294 kB]
Get:32 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libfreetype6 amd64 2.10.4+dfsg-1 [418 kB]
Get:33 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libfontconfig1 amd64 2.13.1-4.2 [347 kB]
Get:34 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libjpeg62-turbo amd64 1:2.0.6-4 [151 kB]
Get:35 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libdeflate0 amd64 1.7-1 [53.1 kB]
Get:36 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libjbig0 amd64 2.1-3.1+b2 [31.0 kB]
Get:37 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libwebp6 amd64 0.6.1-2.1 [258 kB]
Get:38 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libtiff5 amd64 4.2.0-1 [289 kB]
Get:39 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libxau6 amd64 1:1.0.9-1 [19.7 kB]
Get:40 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libxdmcp6 amd64 1:1.1.2-3 [26.3 kB]
Get:41 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libxcb1 amd64 1.14-3 [140 kB]
Get:42 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libx11-data all 2:1.7.2-1 [311 kB]
Get:43 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libx11-6 amd64 2:1.7.2-1 [772 kB]
Get:44 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libxpm4 amd64 1:3.5.12-1 [49.1 kB]
Get:45 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libgd3 amd64 2.3.0-2 [137 kB]
Get:46 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libc-devtools amd64 2.31-13+deb11u2 [245 kB]
Err:47 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 5.10.70-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 199.232.22.132 80]
Get:48 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libcrypt-dev amd64 1:4.4.18-4 [104 kB]
Get:49 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libtirpc-dev amd64 1.3.1-1 [190 kB]
Get:50 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libnsl-dev amd64 1.3.0-2 [66.4 kB]
Get:51 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libc6-dev amd64 2.31-13+deb11u2 [2344 kB]
Get:52 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 manpages-dev all 5.10-1 [2309 kB]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_5.10.70-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 199.232.22.132 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
Fetched 53.4 MB in 2s (22.1 MB/s)
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install gcc -y' returned a non-zero code: 100
ERROR: Service 'flask-dev' failed to build : Build failed
```

Content of `docker-compose-mssql.yml` file below:

```
version: "3"
services:
  # FLASK
  flask-dev:
    container_name: flask-dev
    hostname: flask-dev
    platform: linux/x86_64
    build:
      context: ./server
    volumes:
      - ./server/:/usr/src/app/
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
      - 5678:5678
    env_file:
      - ./env/dev/flask_mssql.env
    networks:
      - appnetwork
      - dbnetwork
 
  db-dev:
    container_name: db-dev
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge:latest
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
    env_file: ./env/dev/mssql_db.env
    volumes:
      - my_dbdata:/var/lib/azuresqledge/data
    networks:
      - dbnetwork

networks:
  dbnetwork:
    driver: bridge
  appnetwork:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  my_dbdata:
  pgadmin:
```

Contents of my `Dockerfile` are as follows:
FROM python:3.7-slim

ENV APP_HOME /usr/src/app

```
WORKDIR ${APP_HOME}

# Initial setup
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat
RUN apt-get --assume-yes update
RUN apt-get --assume-yes install freetds-dev freetds-bin

RUN apt-get install gcc -y
RUN apt-get install libssl-dev -y
RUN apt-get install unixodbc -y 
RUN apt-get install unixodbc-dev -y 
RUN apt-get install freetds-dev -y 
RUN apt-get install freetds-bin -y 
RUN apt-get install tdsodbc -y 
RUN apt-get install --reinstall build-essential -y

#RUN apt-get update \
# && apt-get install unixodbc -y \
# && apt-get install unixodbc-dev -y \
# && apt-get install freetds-dev -y \
# && apt-get install freetds-bin -y \
# && apt-get install tdsodbc -y \
# && apt-get install --reinstall build-essential -y
#
## populate "ocbcinst.ini"
#RUN echo "[FreeTDS]\n\
#Description = FreeTDS unixODBC Driver\n\
#Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so\n\
#Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so" >> /etc/odbcinst.ini
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN mkdir -p /home/vagrant/app-data/

# Copy all files
COPY . .

# Run entrypoint checks
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

I updated the source list to this: https://gist.github.com/ishad0w/788555191c7037e249a439542c53e170 but and able to run `apt-get update` without any error but the above problem still persist. Please help!

This line in `Dockerfile` is giving me error: `RUN apt-get install gcc -y` being not able to find the file `linux-libc-dev_5.10.70-1_amd64.deb` [here](https://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/linux/), but when I run `sudo apt-get install gcc` manually it is working as expected without any error.

Comment: What OS (and OS version) do you have? It looks like you are using the Debian Bullseye package repo, which seems strange assuming you are using Ubuntu.

Comment: I am using 20.04.3 LTS Ubuntu and this is my [source list](https://gist.github.com/ishad0w/788555191c7037e249a439542c53e170), so not sure why it is trying to fetch bullseye.

Comment: `apt list curl
Listing... Done
curl/focal-updates,focal-security,now 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.7 amd64 [installed]
curl/focal-updates,focal-security 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.7 i386
`

Comment: Never mind, my bad. Those sources are for the Docker container, not the host system. You're fine.

Comment: it was working fine yesterday, dunno why this happened today :'(

Comment: The package it is trying to look up does not exist but [this one](https://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_5.10.70-1~bpo10+1_amd64.deb) does.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. For me the issue was that my "apt update -y" step was cached and thus contained wrong repo's. Fixed it by forcing it to not use cache. Looks the same for your step 4 :)

To clear the cache before run use `docker builder prune` or if that doesn't work (as it didn't for me) try something more aggressive such as `docker system prune --all`